# Using PHP, Sendmail, and Undisclosed Recipients

Tags: php, sendmail, amazon-ses

I'm switching a web app over to AmazonSES. We're using PHP 5.3, PHPMailer, and we tried using the AmazonSES pear package but for some reason it was unbelievably slow on the live server. We switched to the Amazon perl script thats use sendmail instead and it's much faster.

However, the Undisclosed Recipients feature (built in to AmazonSES pear code) was no longer available. No matter what I do, the only thing I can get working it by addressing an email as `"To: Undisclosed Recipients <workingadd@domain.com>"`

The problem is that the working address HAS to be there: php's mail() func require it, phpmailer requires it. The problem is, using noreply@ fails, but workingaddress@ works. While the recipient list is protected, we end up getting all the emails at that address.

However, the Amazon code managed to send mails without a primary address. I can't find anything in their code that suggests the answer, nor on the net.

Please help!

Comment: instead of using a large number of bcc's with the 'undisclosed Recipients' why not loop through the addresses and send one 'normal' email to each

Comment: because that consumes a lot more resources on the server, and is a much larger number of api requests to amazon. It's been proven that it works, I just need to figure out how to make it work with sendmail or mail()

Comment: ok, but that adds 3-4 points to the SpamAssassin score, which is why no one uses it (commercially) anymore.

Comment: I've read that it was an accepted way to properly send but will research more then, However I should clarify that this is for transactional email, not any sort of bulk-marketing.

Comment: I have written mailing list software, i don't agree its a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, You want to send mail, Please careful that MTAs don't you as SPAM, if you want to know all of its rules please read all of rules of [SpamHaus](http://www.spamhaus.org)

Answer (score 0):

Set up an interim relay server with postfix or sendmail.  Have your application send emails to that server.  Have that server connect to amazon and send the mail to it.  Let it handle the authentication, etc.  It works extremely well.

--David